# ReportViewer in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use reportviewer in sharepoint. I added the assemblies required and created an aspx calling the rsweb:reportviewer.

I get this error **In remote mode, the Report Viewer control requires session state be enabled or Report Server connection information specified in the config file.**

can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set `EnableSessionState = true` in you page directive in your aspx page. Add the following code in the System.WebServer/Modules section.

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
```